# Prove that if the column vectors of a matrix A are linearly independent, A is invertible.

Tags: linear-algebra

So I think I have this proof. Please let me know if it works:

1) The column vectors of a matrix Q are linearly independent

2) rref(Q) is the identity matrix

3) A matrix is invertible if and only if the rref of the matrix is the identity matrix

4) Therefore, Q is invertible

Please let me know if there are other, more elegant proofs.

Comment: That's good enough.

Comment: This is, of course, for a square matrix.

Comment: Really! :) I thought for sure premise 3 would get me in trouble.